# JavaScript function - Not passing parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jQuery Terminal. Created a command named as `websites`. Whenever someone type a command `websites` `this.echo` hits. And it will display a hyperlinked text `Test`. When I click on it. It calls a function `Test()` and will alert.

```
websites: function() {
    this.echo('<a target="_blank" href="" onclick="Test()">Test</a>', {raw:true});
},
```

Test Function:

```
function test(){
    alert('Success');
}
```

But the problem is, I want to pass URL as parameter to `Test()` function. And display in alert box.

I've tried it in this way.

```
websites: function() {
    this.echo('<a target="_blank" href="" onclick="Test(http://www.google.com)">Test</a>', {raw:true});
},
```

Test Function with Parameters:

```
function test(url){
    alert(url);
}
```

But it never goes to `Test()` function.

I know, there is a syntax mistake. But didn't figure it out so far.

Comment: wouldn't the `this` in the `websites` function be the function?

Comment: You need to wrap your URL in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a string like

```js
function Test(x){
        alert(x);
    }
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="" onclick="Test('http://www.google.com')">Test</a>
```

Comment: Yes. Its working fine with plain html.
I need to be working with this.echo :)